# How are multiple result sets accessed in slick?

Tags: scala, jdbc

How does Slick handle a query that returns multiple result sets?

For example, if I wanted to retrieve information about a table using `sp_help someTableName`

Which would return a number of result sets.  I can get the first result set, simply using `scala.slick.jdbc.StaticQuery.queryNA[Tuple4[String, String, String,String]]("sp_help tblInbox_membership").first()`

How do I get the second result set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be using Sybase or maybe SqlServer.

I'm not familiar with Slick (yet), but the way to access subsequent `ResultSet`s from a statement in JDBC is to call `Statement.getMoreResults()`, then if that succeeds `Statement.getResultSet()`. Slick gives you a Statement object with `Session.withStatement`, so you could at least use the JDBC api to get your resultsets, or feed the ResultSet to Slick if there is a way to do that.

Comment: Thanks Richard.  You're right about SqlServer, how'd you guess? ;)  I'll try this out tonight and if it works I'll come back and mark this as the answer.

Comment: This was nearly there.  It turns out Session.createStatement instead of Session.withStatement was needed.

Comment: Cool! sp_help and the multiple resultset feature both originated with Sybase, and SqlServer inherited them when it was forked from an early version of Sybase.

Comment: Shame, my edit was rejected :/  So here's the code block in a comment without any formating!

def getSecondResultSet() = {
    val database = Database.forURL(jdbcServerURL)
    val session = database.createSession()
    val statement = session.createStatement() //at this point we've left Slick and are operating on java.sql.* objects
    statement.execute("sp_help tblInbox_membership")
    val firstResultSet = statement.getResultSet()
    statement.getMoreResults()
    statement.getResultSet()
}